# laravel redirect custom url that come with query string after login?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.4, redirect

i'm making a website and sending an email for login with query string parameters that continue url to after login like below.

> www.example.com/login?continue=setting%2Femail%2Fnotifications

and i want that

> user redirect to **setting/email/notifications** link after login but not redirect.

user redirect always LoginController $redirectTo property.

Why ? and How could i do this?

this is redirectPath in LoginController

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `redirectTo` method.
Remove `$redirectTo` variable and add something like this:

```
protected function redirectTo(Request $request)
{
    $continue = $request->input('continue');

    return redirect($continue);
}
```